# How to toggle between "Portrait" and "Landscape Right" orientation in iOS simulators via AppleScript?

Tags: macos, ios, applescript, xcode-simulator

How do I toggle between "Portrait" and "Landscape Right" orientation in the iOS simulators via AppleScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, using **Script Editor**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me to toggle between **Portrait** and **Landscape Right** of the **Simulator** *window*:

```applescript
tell application "Simulator" to activate

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Simulator" to ¬
        tell menu 1 of ¬
            menu item "Orientation" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "Device" of ¬
            menu bar 1
            if value of ¬
                attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of ¬
                menu item "Portrait" is "✓" then
                click menu item "Landscape Right"
            else if value of ¬
                attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of ¬
                menu item "Landscape Right" is "✓" then
                click menu item "Portrait"
            end if
        end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hi @user3439894, I understood now and was hit by covid, so wasn't active so much. The above solution worked and thanks for that, marked it as accepted too and will keep in mind always to mark in future. Can you please help me with this question too,  have been stuck in this for last 2 days. 
This is the link for the new question I posted : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422951/how-to-make-every-time-last-option-selected-in-case-of-service-workers-sites-in?noredirect=1#comment597127_422951